# vim no tab completion in bash

Tags: bash, vim, autocomplete

When in `shell`, running `vim <anything>` and pressing `tab`, doesn't auto complete or show the list of the available files. Although it auto completes for the directory names, but not the file names.

Also if I use the full path of the actual vim used like `/usr/bin/vim.gnome` or `/usr/bin/vim.basic` it completes the files fine.

I've tried to use `update-alternatives`, creating symlinks manually, even `cp /usr/bin/vim.basic /usr/bin/vim`, nothing works if I just use `vim` without the full path.

**Edit:**

Additional info:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim

$ ls -l /usr/bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Aug 11 08:27 /usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim

$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Aug 11 08:28 /etc/alternatives/vim -> /usr/bin/vim.gnome

$ whereis vim
vim: /usr/bin/vim.gnome /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim.basic /usr/bin/vim.tiny     /etc/vim /usr/share/vim /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
```

And `$ vim .pro` (even if `/usr/bin/vim` is used) auto completes to `$ vim .prozilla\`, but `$ /usr/bin/vim.gnome .pro` gives proper suggestions, including `.profile` file as well:

```
$ /usr/bin/vim.gnome .pro
.profile   .prozilla/
```

Comment: "which vim"  gives you what output?

Comment: What about others commands like cp or ls those works??

Comment: Yes, other commands work fine, and also vim if /usr/bin/vim.gnome or /usr/bin/vim.basic, etc. are used (but not for /usr/bin/vim although)